# asInvoker for COM dlls and exes?

Tags: uac, manifest

I have an unmanaged windows service. I've included a manifest with "requiresAdministrator" as the requested execution level.

What's the proper execution level for COM dlls and COM exes loaded by the service? Should they be set to "asInvoker" or should they have their own level (and will the COM dlls always use the execution level of the service no matter what is in their manifest)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, services are not under UAC. Your manifest will have no effect on a service and if it's running under an "admin" identity it will have access to whatever resources you need access to.

Second, if your app is not a service, and it has a manifest and is elevated, whatever it launches will be elevated regardless of its own manifest. There are some complex techniques to launch non-elevated from elevated should that be important to you.

Comment: I've been out of the office for a while...thanks for answering. Does this mean that processes launched via a COM interface from a service also are not subject to UAC?